# Real world example of OOPS

Tags: asp.net, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I am very much curious to know the practical implementation of object oriented features like Polymorphism, inheritance, abstract and virtual classes.

On internet I can see examples related to car, ball etc. but I didn't find anything related to a real world scenerio like for example

I have a shopping website, which has 4 roles

> 1. **Admin:** who will watch/modify the
>      site
> 2. **Employee:** Who are the employees of
>      that site
> 3. **Internet User:** Who will buy the
>      product
> 4. **Whole sale dealer:** Who will use the
>      different interface on the same site
>      to buy products in bulk.

Each and every role can modify the product as per the need.

Example: While ordering t-shirst user wants to put his text, color... etc

Any suggestions as to, where I can use concepts like virtual class, abstract class, inheritance in it?

Just curious to know how can it optimize the performance, reliability and scalability.

Comment: Have you started writing code yet? This is one thing that you must do to learn and understand OOPS.

Comment: @Kangkan I do write codes and I learned basics of OOPS. Yes I use inheritance when creating class to get all the feature of base class. but seems like my knowledge is limited :-(

Comment: yea I would avoid oop....I find it adds unnecessary indirection.  And as a beginner you will most certainly make it more complicated than it needs to be.  I know I did.

Comment: @eat_a_lemon I think it's a critical part of the learning process, to design something so over-complicated. There's no better way to learn the kiss principle than to be burned by your own spaghetti..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment about OOP: Things like OOP form patterns or ways of structuring code, from the way you've asked the question, it seems you are learning and want to utilise these patterns, this good and I would recommend this kind of thinking (and being conscious of how code is constructed). Recognising these patterns and structures comes with experience in both using and developing for differnt types of frameworks to acheive specific goals. I dont think there is an answer for all your question, as books have been written about this, but continue reading and developing code and these things will become natural.

Comment: It is really helpful. I will read couple of books to understand it better. Could you recommend me any book for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `ASP.Net` , why not examine how this works in relation to OOP principals, `ASP.Net`  is heavily reliant on these principals.

For example most of the controls in `ASP.Net` [follow this hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx).

```
System.Web.UI.Control --> System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl --> TheControl
```

[Http handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implement `IHttpHandler` and there is the [PageHandlerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagehandlerfactory.aspx)

I feel this is a very real world example of these principals.

Answer (score -1):

real time example for stack: the idly cooker we use is an eg of stack.. the plate which we keep inside the cooker will b taken last..ie lifo...
queue: of course a queue in a bank... first came person wil b served first

Answer (score -2):

OOPs real time example make the ideas very clear

http://blogs.siliconindia.com/Balaganesh/OOPs_with_Real_time_Examples-bid-wQXtvM3e90960669.html

go through it, the way he conveying is simple and clear